# Any example/idea of how to plot the U-MATRIX using python (working on SOM)?

Tags: python, plot, som

Working on SOM implementation using Python ? I want to know how to generate the u-matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One implementation can be found in the [SUSI](https://github.com/felixriese/susi) package (`pip3 install susi`). You can use it like that:

```py
import susi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# get data (replace this part with your data)
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, n_features=2, centers=3)

# initialize and fit SOM
som = susi.SOMClustering()
som.fit(X)

u_matrix = som.get_u_matrix()
plt.imshow(np.squeeze(u_matrix), cmap="Greys")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

which results in this plot:

[image: U-Matrix of SOM]

The code and the plot are taken from [susi/SOMClustering.ipynb](https://github.com/felixriese/susi/blob/master/examples/SOMClustering.ipynb). You find the implementation of the u-matrix there as well.